# How is user information stored in ElasticSearch database of Stack Exchange network?

Tags: discussion, login, authentication, elasticsearch

How is user information stored in the ElasticSearch database of the StackExchange network?

I know that SO and the other websites of the same family use ElasticSearch database to store the data, but how is user information/account stored?

I mean hashes, usernames and so on.

Does it use OAuth2 or some other mechanism?

Comment: As far as I know, there are some database tables for this purpose, but all are part of Stack Exchange own database, not hosted on external servers. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 6):

> How is user information stored in the ElasticSearch database of the StackExchange network?

It pretty much isn't. We use ElasticSearch for... search. Of questions and answers, part of the information includes who authored and edited the posts, but we do not store these.

User and account information is stored in our SQL databases. We do not store passwords as we use OpenId/OAuth2 for authentication.

Comment: I guess the next question is: where are the SE OpenID passwords saved and how?

Comment: @PatrickHofman - they are stored in the OpenId database (a SQL database). All of the user data is hashed prior to storage, using a cryptographically secure hash (including passwords, user names etc...).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: No problem. I didn't consider the OpenId provider to be part of the Q&A network, as such. It is a completely separate codebase (though, yes, there are a few integration points - those are using the internal network and communicate over an encrypted connection).

Comment: I agree but in the concern of OP how it is saved, that would be the logical next question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman How can it be that all the user data is hashed? For example, you don't want to hash the username, you want to retrieve and show the username, isn't it?

Comment: @G_G - most of the user data for the OpenId provider is hashed, items that need to be retrieved are encrypted.

Comment: @Oded but if we use OpenId we don't need to store anything about the user... am I right?

Comment: @G_G - I am talking about the Stack Exchange OpenId provider (which acts like Google or Facebook in that capacity). The Q&A sties themselves do not store any passwords.